# What version of IE is used in XPiNC?

Tags: internet-explorer, xpages, lotus-notes, xpinc

You're supposed to be able to switch between the embedded browsers:
http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8M4KG2

But I can't get it to work. In my case if defaults to using Mozilla on Win7 - IBM Notes 8.5.3FP3 UP1.

Does anyone know what version of IE that's shipped with my version of Notes? I'm suspecting it's not the same version that's installed with the OS(?).

Thanks!

/J

Comment: The embedded browser is what notes uses to open a URL when you click on a link in the email. That is not the same as XPiNC browser which is the equivalent of Firefox 3.6. IE does not ship with notes that comes from the operating system.

Comment: To quote from the source, "The embedded browser in the Notes client uses an operating system dependent default engine". That is not the same as XPinC. XPinC uses the equivalent of Firefox 3.6. When you switch the embedded browser, that's only switching the embedded browser, not the XPinC browser. See File-Preferences-Web Browser and switch to the embedded browser, then click on a HTTP URL in a Notes document and watch the browser open in your Notes client.

Comment: Aha! NOW even I get it! =) Ok, so XULRunner is always used for XPiNC purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is (C) Microsoft and IBM wouldn't be able to ship it (Chromium, the Chrome core) would be a different story. XULrunner, a step sister of Firefox was choosen to be able to provide the integration into the Notes client like opening new windows or sending/receiving composite events. XULrunner has been a little neglegted by the Mozilla team (at some time they wanted even to abandon it, so IBM had to interveen), so the version deemed fit for XPiNC use is still 3.6 Some upgrade work would be needed here (I have no visibility into IBM's plans here)